# Load the relevant home pagebut doesn't login to the site

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

My java code load the relevant home page but doesn't log In to the site.

My code:

```
package queries;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



public class Q {
{

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:\\\\Software\\\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://10.20.10.16/MaharajaICLQA");
```

I am trying to logIn to page and try to get to values in pages.In that case this code works only towards loading the homepage.here below is the code to log and for the rest of the process. This only load the Homepage and not login to the site, why is that happens?

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String baseUrl = null;
driver.get(baseUrl + ("http://10.20.10.16/MaharajaICLQA/Login.aspx?lo=1"));



((WebElement) driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName"))).clear();
((WebElement)driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName"))).sendKeys("Priyasad"); 

((WebElement) driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"))).clear();

((WebElement) driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"))).sendKeys("lakpriya");

((WebElement) driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("btnLogin_CD"))).click();




 driver.navigate().to("http://10.20.10.16/MaharajaICLQA/Returns_CC.aspx");
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//* [@id='cphbody_gvRowData_DXFooterRow']/td[20]"));
 List<String> pageOneValues = new ArrayList<>();
 pageOneValues.add(element.getText());





 driver.navigate().to("http://10.20.10.16/MaharajaICLQA/Reports/CustomVNetSales.aspx");
 WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cphbody_gvSales_DXDataRow14']/td[33]"));
 Assert.assertEquals(pageOneValues.get(0), element2.getText());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two lines

```
String baseUrl = null;
driver.get(baseUrl + ("http://10.20.10.16/MaharajaICLQA/Login.aspx?lo=1"));
```

will cause selenium to make a request to

```
nullhttp://10.20.10.16/MaharajaICLQA/Login.aspx?lo=1
^^^^
```

That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support